# Detail View filled with plist information

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I've been following a tutorial on iOS development - specifically drill-down UITableViews. I have my own custom plist established, but I can't seem to get the DetailViewController to populate with my plist information. I could really use some help here, I'm a bit over my head!

**edit: Here's some details...**

The app works through a plist-populated RootViewController, which is a UITableView. When there aren't any children left in the plist, it changes to a Detail view:

`AppDelegate.m`

```
NSDictionary *tempDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"]];
self.data = tempDict;
```

`RootViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        if(CurrentLevel == 0) { // At the 'root' of the plist

            //Initilalize our table data source
            NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
            self.tableDataSource = tempArray;

            AppDelegate *AppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            self.tableDataSource = [AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"Rows"];

            self.navigationItem.title = @"PedalTome";
        }
        else
            self.navigationItem.title = CurrentTitle;
    }
```

later on...

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        //Get the dictionary of the selected data source.
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Get the children of the present item.
        NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];

        if([Children count] == 0) {

            DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

        }
        else {

            //Prepare to tableview.
            RootViewController *rvController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

            //Increment the Current View
            rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;

            //Set the title;
            rvController.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

            //Push the new table view on the stack
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];

            rvController.tableDataSource = Children;

        }
    }
```

My `DetailViewController.m` is empty, with the exception of a placeholder `self.navigationController.title`.

If I'm understanding correctly, I need to pass information from `RootViewController` to `DetailViewController` - the location and implementation of the plist, the index level (is that what it's called) in the plist, and the string inside that index level (under the key **Detail**).

At this point, any progress is amazing progress. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Kristian, I'm sure someone will answer this in the next 5 seconds but for more general Objc/iOS help check out http://jlawr3nc3.github.com it's a collection of examples I'm currently working on.

Comment: Beautiful website Jack. I've bookmarked it for future reference. Anything there relevant to this problem?

Comment: Thanks, generated from my github README markdown file using http://documentup.com/. I've answered your question below. Feel free to use the comments section to ask questions/tell me I'm totally wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass whatever information you need to your `DetailViewController` by setting up a synthesized property in your `DetailViewController`, and then passing your data to it inside your if-block.

For example, in your `DetailViewController.h` you would have the following (without ARC):

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDictionary *myAwesomeDictionary;
```

Or, with ARC enabled:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *myAwesomeDictionary;
```

Then in `DetailViewController.m` you would have the following:

```
@synthesize myAwesomeDictionary;
```

Then you would change your code block to the following:

```
if([Children count] == 0) {
    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [dvController setMyAwesomeDictionary:dictionary];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
}
```

This assumes that the `NSDictionary` called `dictionary` that you created a few lines above is the data that you'd like to show in your `DetailViewController`.

Then in your `DetailViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:` method you can access that dictionary using `self.myAwesomeDictionary` and do whatever you need to do with it.

*Disclaimer:*

Two things seem to go against Apple's code style standards in your code:

1. Your `AppDelegate` stores your model (your plist). - Apple says that you shouldn't crowd your `AppDelegate` with global data/logic. In general, only write code that pertains specifically to a class, in that specific class.
2. You aren't parsing your plist into custom objects. - This makes it hard to code because you constantly have to figure out what your generic Array and Dictionary objects represent, and make your code totally unreadable for other people.
3. Some of your instance variable names are capitalized. For example, `NSArray *Children` should be `NSArray *children` and `CurrentLevel` should be `currentLevel`. Only Class names have the first letter capitalized.

Check out http://jlawr3nc3.github.com - specifically my CompanyRecords example code for information on how to make a class and FunWithArrays for how to parse a plist into custom objects. MusicLibraryiOS then delves into how to take a plist, parse it into custom objects, and then display it in a `UITableView` along with a detail view.

Comment: I looked at your FunWithArrays app and my issue is that the nature of my app requires being able to drill-down through the plist to the degree I specify in the plist. Is that possible in FunWithArrays?

Comment: It doesn't cover that exactly but FunWithArrays, in conjunction with MusicLibraryiOS, does cover having an array of object in a table view drilling down into a single object. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you need. Since we're sort of moving off the topic of the question, I'll shoot you an email with my contact info.

Answer (score 0):

[Table View Specifier](https://github.com/Stunner/Table-View-Specifier) May do what you need.

> Specified Table View is an iOS table view that has its contents specified
>   via a plist file. Its purpose is largely demonstrative but is also designed 
>   to be used in a live product (useful for credits pages). Can be used with
>   iOS version 4.2 and above.

A dig through their code will most likely be enlightening.